# CSS clamp function formula for font-size

Tags: css, responsive-design, responsive, clamp

How can I use the clamp function, for my h1 element, to change the font-size **responsive** with specific requirements.

```
h1 { font-size: clamp(min, ???, max); }
```

Only from a screen width of 576px should "clamp" increase the size of the font proportionally/responsive up to a screen width of 1200px.

```
@media (min-width: 576px) 
{
    h1 { font-size: clamp(32.44px, ???, 61.04px); }

}
```

Is there a formula to calculate the green area in the picture?

[image]

Comment: https://clamp.font-size.app/

Comment: https://utopia.fyi/type/calculator/

Comment: That should work. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

slope = (maxFontSize - minFontSize) / (maxWidth - minWidth)

yAxisIntersection = -minWidth * slope + minFontSize

preferredValue = yAxisIntersection[rem] + (slope * 100)[vw]

---

On this Website, I found the formula to calculate the value for clamp.

[Linearly Scale font-size with CSS clamp() Based on the Viewport](https://css-tricks.com/linearly-scale-font-size-with-css-clamp-based-on-the-viewport/)

---

The calculation example for my situation:

- maxFontSize = 61.04px or 3,81rem
- minFontSize = 32.44px or 2,0275rem
- maxWidth = 1200px or 75rem
- minWidth = 576px or 36rem
- slope = ( 3,815 - 2,0275) / ( 75 - 36 )
- slope = 1,7875 / 39
- slope = 0,045833
- yAxisIntersection = -36 * slope + 2,0275
- yAxisIntersection = 0,3775
- preferredValue = yAxisIntersection[rem] + (slope * 100)[vw]
- preferredValue = 0,3775rem + 4,5833vw
- **clamp(2,0275rem, 0,3775rem + 4,5833vw, 3,815rem);**

---

[Temani Afif](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8620333/temani-afif) found a website where you can calculate the value.
[Font-size Clamp Generator](https://clamp.font-size.app/)